# Is it appropriate to subtract bias when generating pseudo-random numbers?

Tags: probability, statistics, random

Lets say I want to generate 10,000 random samples from a normal distribution. Is there anything wrong with first generating 10,000 numbers, then computing the mean (which will be a value close to 0) of the population, and finally subtracting this mean from each sample? Doing so gets me 10,000 samples that truly do have a mean of 0.

Further, could we do a similar "correction" for the variance? We could do this by dividing each sample by the standard deviation of the population. After doing this correction, we could then correct the mean as described above.

These procedures will give us a population that truly has a mean of 0 and variance of 1, which is what we wanted. However, I'm not sure if these procedures introduce problems that I am not aware of?

Comment: I would argue that this is not a goal to shoot for. Random outcomes really will be random and asymmetrical. If we flipped a fair coin 100 times, would we "correct" by manually turning over some of the coins so that we had exactly 50 heads and 50 tails?

Comment: If you do what you propose, the values won't be independent.

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers are independent normal distributed random numbers, that’s as good as it gets. If you “correct” a sequence, it’s not random anymore. It can easily be distinguished from a random sequence - because the average is too close to 0.

Comment: It seems to me that adding a constant to all our numbers does not make them not random though? For example, If we want a gausian distribution with a mean of 1, we would first generate a normal distribution, and then add 1 to each element.